# react redux component not updates

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a "container" component that has mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps with connect.

In the view component I display the props data, and has a method that calls the container methods.

My problem is that after I update the state (I see it's updated on devtools) the view container is not updated.

I think maybe it's because of the props object is complex...

**** found the source, can't really understand why but somebody here will, hopefully.

When I use a "global" variable inside the "mapStateToProps", that problem appeared, when I simply pasted the content inside instead with a static variable all worked well.

code:

```
//this is what was the problem HERE
let staticVariable = [ ... ];

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {

    let review = state.reviews.reviews.reviews[props.params.id];

    return {
        review,
        items: staticVariable
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, props) => {
    return {
        whatever: dispatch(updateState())
    };
};

let OverviewContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Overview);
export default OverviewContainer;
```

just for viewing this is the state:

```
{
    something: {},
    something2: {},
    something3: {},
    reviews: {
        dontcare: 1,
        reviews: {
            reviews: {
                1: {
                    dontcare: 1,
                    assets: [
                        {

                        }
                    ]   
                }             
            }
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: is this your exact code? the return of `mapDispatchToProps` would throw a syntax error if so

Comment: its not copy pasted, just added the relevant things...

Comment: your `mapDispatchToProps` looks very strange though because you're not passing dispatch, you're actually *calling* dispatch... which doesn't make any sense. can you also post the rest of the component?

Comment: 99.9% of the time, the issue is accidental mutation, usually in a reducer.  See http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-not-rerendering .  You might want to post your reducer logic here.

Comment: just updated the post, found the problem, but really dont know why this kind of thing causes it... any ideas?

Comment: As mentioned above, this is probably a mutation issue. If you manipulate `staticVariable` and expect it to cause a re-render, you should make sure that it's replaced by a new array (otherwise the reference stays the same).